# How do I stop the menu appearing behind the images and banners, whilst keeping it at a fixed position?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, toggle

I'm attempting to learn how to build a website and build myself a portfolio, http://www.tom.lostinawesome.co.uk is the site.

It has all been thrown together with bits and pieces of code the menu I wanted to use was supposed to appear with a toggle and then open when you press the button.

Instead the menu doesn't appear until you scroll down, it's already open and appears from behind each banner and behind other content.

Comment: add some offending code then maybe we can help you.

Comment: links to work in progress quickly become obsolete: once you read the first correct answer and edit your development site the question then becomes useless as the problem is no longer demonstrable. Build a JSFiddle that shows the problem and put the code that errors in the question

Answer (score 2):

Add `z-index:9999` attribute to hbar id (header.css line 26)

```
#hbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  background: #292929;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0C0C0C;
  color: #dddddd;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

and add `z-index:1` attribute section.section.parallax class (main.css line 231):

```
section.section.parallax {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @ToniLeigh, yes you are right. Just edited it now. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is working now.